# Почему при смене и востановлении бинарного файла (jpeg картинки) ее открыть уже не возможно?

Tags: binary, jpeg

Если открыть картинку (или другой файл) в текстовом режиме и сменить/добавить что-то, то файл будет поврежден, но если потом вернуть все на место (сменить назад/удалить добавленный символ), то файл все равно битый. Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что текстовый редактор не предназначен для редактирования двоичных файлов, и, когда вы возвращаете символ на место, на самом деле где-то что-то все равно смещается, какие-то байты добавляются, вроде перевода строки, и все в точности как было не восстанавливается.

Если вы откроете тот же файл в Hex-редакторе, предназначенном для двоичных файлов, то сначала добавите символ, потом сотрете - и файл восстановит свою функциональность.